# In which dialects does "is wanting" work as an appropriate substitution for "wants"?

Tags: tenses, dialects

I've recently seen a movie character regularly use this construction (for example, "the dog is wanting to be taken out for a walk"), and I am trying to figure out which dialect or cultural background the construction is meant to signal.

Comment: What movie did you see it in?

Comment: I'm going through the TV Guide listings trying to figure it out, doesn't seem to be easy.

Comment: I've heard this before, and it seems to be a "passivication" of the active voice in wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't conclusively say if this is a reflection of the dialect, but my mother-in-law uses this construction and she is from Arkansas.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is fairly common in speakers from north-east England and Scotland. As a child, we subscribed to the Beano comic, which was printed in Dundee, and characters would often use this sort of phrase, which sounded odd to my London-based family.

Answer (score 0):

I heave heard Indians (from India) speak like this. It's quite common in that dialect.

Comment: The progressive tense is common, but the specific construction "is wanting" is not. You may hear "the dog is asking to be taken out for a walk" (or "waiting to be…", etc.), but "wanting to be" wouldn't be common.

Comment: Ah, you are right. That is what I heard.